# Multiple SSH tunnel hops with DBeaver

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, dbeaver

Can DBeaver create two SSH tunnels and then connect to a database?

I have successfully created one SSH tunnel but not two.

I am trying to connect to an AWS RDS database via Bastion host. Bastion host only allows SSH access from my corporate IP range.
This means that when I am in the office I can connect to the RDS from DBeaver just fine:

1. My computer is in the allowed IP range
2. DBeaver creates an SSH tunnel to a Bastion host in my VPC inside the AWS cloud
3. DBeaver connects to the RDS database

The issue arises when I work from home.
I would have to add "zero" step to have an allowed IP address for the Bastion host connection:
0) Connect to the machine inside the office

I have not yet managed to achieve this. Has anyone got an idea of how to do this?

Comment: if you actually have access over ssh to the machine inside the office, you could open up a remote ssh tunnel to the ec2 instance through the office machine.  I don't know if you could do it within dbeaver but you could do it separately, then point the dbeaver ssh tunnel config to the local side of the office machine tunnel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kudos to [@erik258](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1726083/erik258) for pointing me in the right direction.

I have created an SSH tunnel between an office machine and the Bastion host. When in the office machine, when I access `http://localhost:<local_port>` I am in effect communicating with the `<RDS_endpoint>` on port `<remote_port>`.

Steps:

1. Create an SSH tunnel from the office machine to the Bastion host.  [Source](https://www.tunnelsup.com/how-to-create-ssh-tunnels/)

> $ ssh -L <local_port>:<RDS_endpoint>:<remote_port> -i <path_to_ssh_key> ec2-user@<Bastion_host public IP>

`<local_port>` - random port

`<remote_port>` - port RDS endpoint listens to (5432 for PostgreSQL)

`<RDS_endpoint>` - endpoint specified on the AWS RDS page

2. Create DBeaver connection. In the "SSH" section specify your office machine. In "Main" section, set "Host" as `localhost`, and "Port" as `<local_port>`.